# Viewing phase difference between two signals

Tags: oscilloscope, test-equipment

I need the SPI clock and the device clock to be synchronized. I am using an Arduino (ATMega 2560) to communicate with the device. The device clock is being generated from using a timer on the Arduino (16-bit Timer).

The SPI clock is also from the SCK pin on the Arduino (pin 52 in this case). From the ATMEGA2560 data sheet I am sure that both these clocks are derived from the onboard crystal oscillator so theoretically they should be in sync. However, I want to visualize this and then make sure they are in sync. I tried using an oscilloscope, but I am unable to trigger both channels at the same time. I am using a Siglent SDS 1052DL+. Can somebody give me guidance on how to use a scope for this purpose?

Edit: removed Arduino code.

Comment: Similar to question to: [How to calculate phase shift between two square waveforms with Arduino DUE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/how-to-calculate-phase-shift-between-two-square-waveforms-with-arduino-due)

Comment: @KingDuken. I agree. It belongs on: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/how-to-calculate-phase-shift-between-two-square-waveforms-with-arduino-due

Comment: Right you can only trigger on one channel at a time.  It you con't know which is first then you'll have to try it both ways.  I'm not sure what's the longest delay to expect.. for short pulses and long times peak detect sometimes helps

Comment: If your question is about oscilloscope usage, you should remove the code as it's not really relevant.